# Oracle database query has not result under jsp

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, jsp

I would like to retrieve the data in Oracle database. If I use jsp on Tomcat, it has not result, but if I use SQLDeveloper, the result is show. Both sql string are equal.

The sql string is:

```
String q="SELECT pid, pswd, name, lgnpics FROM users WHERE pid='"+ uid + "' and pswd='" + psw + "'";
```

The connection, statement and the resultset realization is:

```
String cs = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(cs, db_user, db_psw);
Statement stmt = cn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(q);
```

If I test it, the resultset is not available, but I know it's a false result.

The connection is ready and if I use a field which doesn't exixts, I get an error, so the statement is ready to use it.

The header of the JSP file is:

```
%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="utf-8" import="java.sql.*,java.io.*,java.util.*"
    session="true"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
```

Could anybody help me why?

UPDATE1: The code what I test the result:

```
if (!rs.next()) {
    out.println("NOK: result set is not available");
} else {
    while (rs.next()) {
        out.write("OK: result is available");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *If I test it, the resultset is not available*: what does that mean? Where is the code reading from the result set. And please, use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), unless you want your app to be a target for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Have you printed the values of uid and psw? They're probably not what you think they are.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. So If I try to test the result(the resultset is available or not), I get it is not exits.

Comment: I have already tried it. I showed it in the browser and tried it in the SQLDeveloper program, which show the result.

Comment: Have you made sure the transaction in SQLDeveloper is committed? Have you made sure that there is no leading or trailing space in uid or psw? Are you sure the user and password used to connect to the database (and thus choose the schema) is the right one?

Comment: There is one user(it is the system user) what I use to connect to the database. I think the connection is ready, because if I use wrong field in the sql string, I get an error. I try the select without filter(select * from users), but the result is same. I also try to insert a new user and it created succesfully under JSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try with this segment:

```js
boolean more = rs.next();

if (!more) {
    out.println("NOK: result set is not available");
} else {
    while (more) {
        out.write("OK: result is available");
  .......
  
  more = rs.next();
    }
}
```

because I believe you can use rs.next() only once as it points out the cursor asap you call it. so it won't reach your while() loop as it is already passed by your if() condition.

Try and see !